# Passing an argument to a void(*)(void*)

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am wrapping some sqlite3 C code in C++ and am confused about this type of argument `void(*)(void*)` in this function

`int sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const void*, int n, void(*)(void*));`

So my wrapper looks like

```
int Query::Blob(int index, const void* blob, int blob_size, void* memory_management){
   return sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, index, blobl, blob_size, memory_management);
}
```

I should be able to pass the following to the last argument

1. Some function to free the blob memory
2. Either `SQLITE_STATIC` or `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` defines

The two defines are unsurprisingly defined as

`typedef void (*sqlite_3_destructor_type)(void*);`

But I really don't understand the void/void syntax. How can I wrap that in my C++ method to accept a function like `delete` or the defines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `void(*)(void*)` is a pointer to a non-member function that takes a single argument of type `void *` and returns `void`.

So if your `memory_management` function is declared as:

```
void memory_management(void *);
```

Then it matches this definition, and `Query::Blob` should be defined as:

```
int Query::Blob(int index, const void* blob, int blob_size, void (*memory_management)(void *)){
   return sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, index, blobl, blob_size, memory_management);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that you need to provide a call back that takes one argument, a pointer to `void` and returns nothing. This has to be a free function (not a non-static method of a class)

Indeed, `free` is such a function. You can use a delete-like as well:

```
void myfree(void* data)
{
    delete static_cast<MyObject*>(data);
}
```

You loose type-safety, but if this is to free an object passed as `void*` somewhere else and also used in callback, this is defined behavior.